# Vapor: how to not receive a particular upload?

Tags: swift, vapor

In [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor), how does one setup to check and decline an upload request prior to any part of such file being uploaded to the server?

My current attempt in Vapor 3 is with a route handler structured like:

```swift
func imagesUploadOneHandler(_ request: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponseStatus> {

    let headers = request.http.headers
    let headersUploadToken: [String] = headers["Upload-Token"]

    if headersUploadToken.count != 1 || headersUploadToken[0] != aValidToken {
        return HTTPResponseStatus.notAcceptable
    }

    // http body content type: 'application/octet-stream'
    let dataFuture: EventLoopFuture<Data> = request.http.body.consumeData(max: 50_000_000, on: request)

    let futureHTTPResponseStatus = dataFuture.map(to: HTTPResponseStatus.self, {
        (data: Data) -> HTTPResponseStatus in
        // ... other code
        return HTTPResponseStatus.ok
    })

    return futureHTTPResponseStatus
}
```

Firstly, the above will not compile.  The line `return HTTPResponseStatus.notAcceptable` has a compile time error "return HTTPResponseStatus.notAcceptable". How to convert `HTTPResponseStatus` to `EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponseStatus>` has been elusive.

Secondly, can some code prior to `request.http.body.consumeData(...)` in a route handler prevent an upload of the file content? Or, is some middleware needed instead to avoid uploading the data content (e.g. some large file) from the `http.body`?

Comment: I don't think you can in a single route. I would use two routes, the first one that takes the filename without attempting the upload does the checking and returns either the decline or a form with the filename already set that the user just has to accept to make the upload happen.

Comment: @Nick, the two route approach is interesting for some situations. However, the particular case that I'm pondering, the upload URL is an exposed API where ideally the upload data body can be accepted or rejected based on some expected header information.